# How to derive number range types

Tags: typescript

This question is as follows:

```js
type numberRange<Min extends number, Max extends number> = ?
type one_to_nine = numberRange<1,9>
const n:one_to_nine = 5 //expected ✅
const m:one_to_nine = 10 //expected ❎
```

[Playground](https://c1ns.cn/swLIW)

My answer is as follows:

```js
type IsMore<A extends number, B extends number, L extends any[] = []> = A extends L['length']
? false
: B extends L['length']
? true
: IsMore<A, B, [...L, any]>
type numRange<Min extends number, Max extends number> = true extends IsMore<infer U, Min>
  ? IsMore<Max, U> extends true
    ? U
    : never
  : never
```

My answer doesn't work. I guess `true extends IsMore<infer U, Min>` leads to the failure.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer!  but i want to know  how to improve my answer, or point out the reason for my incorrect answer.